# Send props in state - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand how to send new variable if I use state.

It's example from React tutorial:

```
var Timer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {secondsElapsed: 0};
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Timer />, mountNode);
```

It works. But If I want to send `secondsElapsed` what should I do?

`<Timer sec={this.props.sec}>`and:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {secondsElapsed: this.props.sec};
  }
```

It doesn't work.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3fZT2/144/) - I should start timer form 10000 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [code](http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/69curevx/2/) below works as expected. Other than making sure there's a default value always for the `initialTime` property, you can initialize the `secondsElapsed` state within `getInitialState`. While doing this could be considered an [anti-pattern](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html), in this case it's not as it's just doing initialization of internal state.

Also, you'll need to implement `componentWillReceiveProps`. This function is called (after the first time) when ever the props to the component have been updated. In this case, the `initialTime` property value was initially `10`, and then changed to `10000`. So, the `nextProps` argument will contain an object with the property `initialTime` set to `10000`.

```
var Timer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { secondsElapsed: this.props.initialTime || 0 };
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
      this.setState({ secondsElapsed: nextProps.initialTime || 0 });
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {  
    return (
      <div>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

If you might be passing a string into `initialTime` as shown above, make sure that you use `parseInt` on the value:

```
return { secondsElapsed: parseInt(this.props.initialTime || '0') };
```

Read more about the component lifecycle [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case `initialTime` has initial state and when loads from JSON. And `initialTime` is `0` always but `initialTime` updates.

Comment: 'componentWillMount: function() { this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.props.initialTime});}' doesn't help too.

Comment: Look my example, please - http://jsfiddle.net/3fZT2/144/ In example I set new time - 10000sec.

Comment: Ahh -- now I understand what you were looking for. See my update with `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out componentWillMount (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

This if you call setState within componentWillMount you are guaranteed it will be updated before it hits render.

Comment: I tried `componentWillUpdate: function() {console.log(1)
     this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.props.duration});
 },` Console prints '1' 1200 times.

Comment: `componentWillMount` change only once. If I change props, nothing change in <Timer>.